# How to enforce node webkit to work offline

Tags: webkit, nw.js

I am using nwjs (previously called node webkit) to interpret HTML and run the underlying javascript code to handle events. As it doesn't need an internet connection, I would like the nwjs window not to be connected to the internet or at least not be able to make connections to remote hosts.

I have tried something like  --host-rules="MAP * 127.0.0.1" inside the chromium-args option in package.json, but this fails (parse error).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set:

```
"chromium-args": "--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1"
```

in package.json